# Are there any recent advances on the combination of deep learning and graphical models?

Tags: neural-networks, references, graphical-model

Could you please introduce some recent papers on this? How to deal with the (approximate) gradient descent for graphical model inference, and then integrate it into the stochastic gradient descent? I know the Domke's workhttp://machinelearning.wustl.edu/mlpapers/papers/AISTATS2012_Domke12 was devoted on this. And the structured prediction energy networks is also on this https://arxiv.org/abs/1703.05667. But the mathematical requirements for both two papers is beyond mine extreme. Could you please show some simpler methods with simpler math derivations?

Comment: RBMs are a pretty reasonable example of graphical models that utilize deep learning. However, as far as I know, they are slowly going out of style.

Comment: Hi @AlexR. thanks a lot for your comment! I actually want to study about the conditional random field based graphical models for image related problems. I think RBMs based graphical models is too high level for me as it is too abstract for me.